# Escape double quotes inside query

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, double-quotes

I'm scratching my head with this and i can't figure what's wrong

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * 
                     FROM `offers` 
                     WHERE 
                     (
                         type='$tran' && 
                         imob='$typeimob' &&
                         (
                           'str_replace("_"," ",$zone)'
                            LIKE CONCAT('%',area,'%')
                         )
                     ) 
                     ORDER BY `price` DESC 
                     LIMIT 0, 50;");
    }
```

This is inside a php.
The problem is that I have to escape the double quotes inside str_replace, and i tried `str_replace(\"_\",\" \",$zone)` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: why do you even need them as double quotes? cant you just use single quotes? why a single quote around the str_replace?

Comment: Also you do realize that `str_replace` won't actually run within a string, regardless of which quotes are used?

Comment: Let's make this even better and *stop* using `mysql_query`.  Switch to PDO or MySQLi then use a prepared statement.  That way, there's no escaping needed and no confusion.

Comment: Build your query first and assign it to a variable. Then pass that variable to `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the output of str_replace() into your string.

```
    $result=mysql_query(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM `offers` 
        WHERE 
        (
        type='$tran' &&
         imob='$typeimob' &&
         (
            '".str_replace("_"," ",$zone)."' 
            LIKE CONCAT('%',area,'%')
            )
        ) 
        ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 0, 50;");
```

By the way, if you are using an IDE like Eclipse PDT, these things will be apparent to you right away :)